# How to pass stream from php link to clappr player?

Tags: javascript, php, clappr

I have a php link that return the url of stream like this: https://myexample.com/test.php?id=xyz

```
<?php
//declare some headers and variables
$_GET["id"];
//Do some curl here
$stream = $result;
echo $stream; //http://myexample.com/xyz.m3u8?token=xxx
?>
```

I would to pass the result of the php link to the my video page that contain clappr player. How do I define the variable src to get the stream link from the php response in the script? I did this way but not working.

```
<div id="player">
</div>
<script>
    var src="https://myexample.com/test.php?id=xyz";
    var player = new Clappr.Player({source: src, 
    autoPlay: true,
    height: 360,
    width: '100%',
    parentId: "#player"
});
  </script>
```

Please help!

Comment: Instead of echoing your $stream URL, you should redirect to it using a `Location` header.

Comment: I changed to header Location, but still not working. It seems that the src variable doesn't get the response from php link.

Comment: If you redirect, then it isn't supposed to "get the response" - the Location header would simply tell the client when it requests `https://myexample.com/test.php?id=xyz`, "please go fetch `http://myexample.com/xyz.m3u8?token=xxx` instead". But we can't tell if you did something wrong, or the player library used perhaps simply doesn't support this, when all the we get from you is "not working". Show what exactly you tried in such a case.

Comment: If you wanted to set your second URL as value for `src` directly - then you need to actually output the value in that location, like shown in the currently existing answer.

Comment: Thank you @Cbroe! I want only my website is able to get videos, not someone can steal it. That why I encoded in the php file and then pass these to the Clappr player. I even tested with JW player but still not able to get the link from php.

Comment: And the token is supposed to prevent this from being used on other sites, because it frequently changes, and gets _verified_ with every request? (If not, then you did not achieve much "protection" to begin with.)

Answer (score -1):

This will work only if javascript is placed in the same file:

```php
<?php $stream = "http://myexample.com/xyz.m3u8?token=xxx"; ?>
var src="<?php echo $stream; ?>";
```

Comment: Thank you but not that way.